# Can't install module in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried to install re and pprint in Google Colab but I keep getting an error. I tried to do it in a new file, but nothing changed... I tried different advices that I found on SO but nothing worked.

[image]

[image]

All the other modules are working as they should.

Is there something that I can do?

Comment: use `!pip install xyz`

Comment: I've tried that too, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Both `re` and `pprint` are built-in with your Python installation.

- [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

You don't need to install them to use them.
They can simply be imported and used as-is.

See the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) docs for other modules you don't need to install.

Comment: Your absolutely right , I just tried to see if it works separately and seems that is working perfectly. I assumed that the problem was with the RE module because the program seemed to work nice until it entered the block where RE module had to start, but I think that it is a problem with another module AST, it keeps getting an error: 

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I'll dig into this one.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @FlorinBaci Just a tip: "*Command errored out with exit status 1*" is usually what's printed at the end of most (if not all) error messages, and is practically useless when used as a Google search query or when asking others. I suggest reading the outputs before that.